# Joining two tables - one with a selection, one untouched

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join two tables and return the total number of records, however the first table must have a WHERE condition to screen out thousands of records first. The first table has the alias 'Poly_NoRoad', and the second table has the alias 'Vri'.

I have tried to nest the first table selection (where I am screening out records based on various Not Like criteria, to end up with a reduced 'Poly_NoRoad' table) then join the results of that selection with the 'Vri' table.

OPENING_ID is a common field in both tables.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Select count(*)
From
  (Select *
  From Whse_Forest_Vegetation.Rslt_Forest_Cover_Poly Poly_Noroad
  Where Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No) Not Like 'PAS%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%WTR%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%WTP%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%RD%'
  And Upper (Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No) Not Like 'RES%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%ROAD%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%LANDING%')

Join Whse_Forest_Vegetation.Veg_Comp_Lyr_R1_Poly Vri 
On Poly_Noroad.Opening_Id = Vri.Opening_Id
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Your sub-query is not aliased. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) AS Poly_Noroad JOIN...`

Comment: The problem is I was getting an error, and the solutions from  @a_horse_with_no_name fixes the problem.

Comment: The solution from @zambonee is essentially correct, just there's no need for the AS keyword in Oracle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give that derived table ("sub-select") an alias, otherwise you can't join to it. The alias *inside* the derived table is not visible on the outside.

```
Select count(*)
From (
  Select *
  From Whse_Forest_Vegetation.Rslt_Forest_Cover_Poly Poly_Noroad
  Where Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No) Not Like 'PAS%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%WTR%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%WTP%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%RD%'
  And Upper (Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No) Not Like 'RES%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%ROAD%'
  And Upper(Poly_Noroad.Silv_Polygon_No)  Not Like '%LANDING%'
) t --<< an alias for the derived table
  Join Whse_Forest_Vegetation.Veg_Comp_Lyr_R1_Poly Vri 
     On t.Opening_Id = Vri.Opening_Id;
        ^
        You need to use the alias of the derived table.
```